# Pandas plotting lines from different columns ignoring values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, split, pandas

If in a pandas dataframe i have two columns like these:

```
df.high
Out[11]: 
date
2004-01-14       NaN
2004-01-15    1.2675
2004-01-16    1.2609
2004-01-19    1.2426
2004-01-20       NaN
2004-01-21       NaN
2004-01-22       NaN
2004-01-23    1.2778
2004-01-26    1.2616  

df.low
Out[12]: 
date
2004-01-14       NaN
2004-01-15    1.2558
2004-01-16    1.2349
2004-01-19    1.2334
2004-01-20       NaN
2004-01-21       NaN
2004-01-22       NaN
2004-01-23    1.2564
2004-01-26    1.2457
```

**How to plot a straight line for every group of values using the first value of the group in df.high and the last of the group in df.low ignoring the values in beetween?**

e.g. In this example the first line must be from df.high 2004-01-15 to df.low 2004-01-19, and the second from df.high 01-23 to df.low 01-26

FYI apart from this example i have really bigger dataframes than this with groups of values alternating with groups of NaNs and i need to keep the datetime index in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can build a function that splits the DataFrame according to the `NaN`s:

```
def mysplit(df):
    parts = np.split(df, np.where(np.isnan(df.value))[0])
    # removing NaN entries
    parts = [part[~np.isnan(part.value)] for part in parts
              if not isinstance(part, np.ndarray)]
    # removing empty DataFrames
    parts = [part for part in parts if not part.empty]
    return parts
```

Then you can run this function for each DataFrame that you have:

```
parts1 = mysplit(df1)
#[                 date   value
#1 2004-01-15 00:00:00  1.2675
#2 2004-01-16 00:00:00  1.2609
#3 2004-01-19 00:00:00  1.2426,
#                 date   value
#7 2004-01-23 00:00:00  1.2778
#8 2004-01-26 00:00:00  1.2616]

parts2 = mysplit(df2)
#[                 date   value
#1 2004-01-15 00:00:00  1.2558
#2 2004-01-16 00:00:00  1.2349
#3 2004-01-19 00:00:00  1.2334,
#                 date   value
#7 2004-01-23 00:00:00  1.2564
#8 2004-01-26 00:00:00  1.2457]
```

Making it easy to plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
values = [[i.values[0,1], i.values[-1,1]] for i,j in zip(parts1, parts2)]
for value in values:
    plt.plot([0,1], value)
```

[image]

---

EDIT: to achieve what you suggested in the comments you can slightly change the last part:

```
for i,j in zip(parts1, parts2):
    plt.plot([i.index[0], j.index[-1]], [i.values[0,1], j.values[-1,1]])
plt.show()
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: Ok it looks good. The only problem is that i want to keep the date index in the original order when plotting. In your example lines are overlapping and the index is changed. Can you help?